# Editor could not be initialized while open feature file cucumber

Tags: selenium, testing, gradle, automation, cucumber

Editor could not be initialized error is displayed while opening the feature file. My feature file for the program is:

```
Feature: Login feature

Scenario: Successful Login with Valid Credentials
    Given User Navigate to LogIn Page
    When User enters UserName and Password
    Then Message displayed Login Successfully
```

Comment: What is the editor the message is referring to? What software is giving that error?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just because there is a compatibility issue with the eclipse version, I am using a neon version of eclipse (greater than0.020) so to prevent this issue we have to use the version less than 0.20 version of eclipse and you will get the solution for it. GO and chill.

Use this Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)